# Jquery - How to select a specific tag of a div tag attribute that contains html?

Tags: jquery

I have a div that has an attribute called 'data-prototype'. That attribute 'data-prototype' contains some html. Nested inside that html is a select tag that I would like to extract. I know how i get the entire attribute content with jquery but not how to get a specific tag (the select tag in my case). Thank you in advance. Cheers. Marc

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gpsw3/

My html:

```
<div id="some-div" data-prototype="<div><span>something</span><select><option>opt1</option><option>opt2</option></select></div>"></div>

<a id="btn">click</a>
```

My Jquery:

```
$(document).on({
            click: function() { 
                $container = $('#some-div');
                alert($container.attr('data-prototype'));
            }
}, '#btn');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a DOM element from the `data-prototype`'s content and then find the given element.

```
var $container = $('#some-div');
var $prototype = $("<div/>").append($container.attr("data-prototype"));
var $select    = $prototype.find("select");
```

Alternatively, you can use `.data()` instead of `.attr()` to access `data-*` attributes.

[**See it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/V6Y57/)

---

Clarifying `$("<div/>").append(...)`. The `.find()` function works on descendants, so you need to wrap your content to be able to select the topmost (root) element in your `data-prototype` attribute.

Comment: Hello Alexander. Thanks for trying to help. How can i see the output of $select? If I alert it with jquery i have [Object Object] returned...

Comment: @Marc, You can use your browser's JavaScript console. Or, you could simple append it to body, `$select.appendTo("body")`. I modified the live example for it

Comment: @Marc, check [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525)

Comment: Thank you alexander. It is working very good. Nevertheless could you explain how the $("<div/>") is to be understood?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/gpsw3/1/

```
$(document).on({
        click: function() { 
            $container = $('#some-div');
            var a = $container.attr('data-prototype');
    var b = a.substr(0, a.indexOf('</div>'));
    var c = b.substr(b.indexOf('<select>'));
    alert(c);
        }
    }, '#btn');
```

I don't think there is other way of doing this (not sure) but this way you can extract the thing you are looking for.

Comment: It's better to use DOM capabilities

Comment: Hello Jai thanks for the help Jai. Your solution works but is not very flexible. I am looking for something where I can search by tag (by the way I did not downvote you...)

Answer (score 0):

Put your data attrebute contents in a DOM selector and then target it

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/gpsw3/3/

```
$(document).on({
    click: function() {
        $container = $('#some-div');
        $nestedHTML = $("<div/>").append($container.attr('data-prototype'));
        $select = $nestedHTML.find('select');
        console.log( $select);
    }
}, '#btn');
```

Comment: How is this any different than my answer?

Comment: Oh Sorry Alexander, i havent seen your answer as i was trying to make a workable example. it is the same as yours. you can take the credit